# deleting a node from a linked list based on a key

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list

Hello i'm trying to delete a node based on a key. I'm learning dictionary implementation and decided to implement it from scratch to fully understand the concept. i successfully was able to add and return the value using 2 node references a head and tail pointer. But i'm having difficulty using the key to delete a node from the list. 
Below is my code to delete from the list

```
public V remove(K key) {
   V result = null;
   if(!this.isEmpty()&&head==tail){ //if head and tail are only nodes in the list
       if(tail.getKey().equals(key)){
       result = tail.getValue();
       head=null;
       tail = null;
       count--; //decrements the count in the list
       }
   }
   else {
        boolean found = false;
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;
        while(current!=null&&!found){
            if(current.getKey().equals(key)){
                previous = current;
                result = current.getValue();
                previous.setNextNode(current.getNextNode());
                previous.setNextNode(null);
                count--;
                found = true;
            }
            current = current.getNextNode();
        }
       }
   return result;
   }
```

when i enter the desired key to be deleted. It deletes all the keys after the desired key to be deleted.
PS it's not a double linked list. I just created a tail node to access the last node in the list

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @nitegazer2003 when i enter the key to be deleted, it deletes all the key after the desired key.

Comment: Your logic is wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i agree something is wrong with the logic but i drew it out on paper and traversed through the node. The problem is when i find the node to be deleted, i have to assign the next node to of the current node to its previous node. That's where i am having the problem

Comment: Why do you call `previous.setNextNode(null);`?

Comment: @jennfitz Please review my code and comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are getting bogged down with updating the list.  This code simplifies your algorithm:

```
// this method returns the head of the new list with the item possibly removed
public Node remove (K key) {
V result = null;
if (this.isEmpty()) {
    return null;                          // return null for empty list
} else if (head.getKey().equals(key)) {
    return head.getNextNode();            // return head if head matches
} else {
   Node current = head;
   Node next = head.getNextNode();

   while (next != null) {                 // walk down the list and search
       if (next.getKey().equals(key)) {
           current.setNextNode(next.getNextNode());
           break;
       }
       current = next;                    // advance list pointers
       next = next.getNextNode();
    }

    return head;                          // will return head for list with 1 element
    }
}
```

Comment: you helped alot. Your code worked as i tried it. Plus i had to worry about the head and tail node and that seem to take care of it. will draw it out on paper and traverse the list. Thanks.

Comment: my concept wasn't far off but apart from setting previous.setNextNode(null) which i know was wrong could you point what was fundamentally wrong? I appreciate the help alot

Comment: You weren't updating the pointers correctly, from what I can tell.  I spent a lot of time taking care of all base cases (1 node, 0 nodes, etc.) to get to the point where I had a `current` pointer to the head, and a `next` pointer to the next node.  After that, I just walk down the list to possibly find the node to delete.

Comment: thanks a lot i drew out the nodes on paper and yes you were taking for all the cases. I appreciate it as i drew it out on paper and yes you were right i was failing to update the pointers correctly. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. You set `previous = current;`, as the first statement, meaning previous and current are always the same.
2. You should remove this line:
   `previous.setNextNode(null);` As you do it right after assigning the new next node.

Comment: yes i commented that out but it doesn't delete the node

Answer (score 0):

You got the general idea, except for 2 things: `previous = current` should be done outside the if block so that it always gets assigned before moving current forward, and `previous.setNextNode(null)` should be removed as it undoes the preceding line.

Also, you need to make a special case when the first node in the list matches the key so you can reassign the head.

```
while(current!=null&&!found){
    if(current.getKey().equals(key)){
        result = current.getValue();
        previous.setNextNode(current.getNextNode());
        count--;
        found = true;
    }
    previous = current;
    current = current.getNextNode();
}
```

Comment: yes that seem to work but i have to worry now about the first and last node